# Azure match one user Office365 <> Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365

I have one user that cannot connect in office365  <> Active Directory.

I only have a problem with that user.

The user had an account in Office365, then I created an account in Active Directory. I matched SMTP. The account has theoretically connected, in the azura I have the information "synchronized directory: no"

There are no errors in synchronization, no duplicates.

Comment: Any errors on Azure AD Connect? and you do not have 2 duplicated account, one "Cloud" and second "On-Premises"?

Comment: Exactly.0 duplicated account(smtp).